What determines enemy spawn rate?
Sometimes if I get a good weapon in WOWOWOW KORONE BOX, I'll spend some time clearing out enemies before collecting a new box. I've been assuming enemy spawn rate increases based on boxes collected, but I'm realizing that if it's based on time passed then I should be collecting boxes as quickly as possible instead.
What determines how frequently enemies spawn? Is it based on the number of boxes collected or does it increase based on time passed?
